# Fetch SharePoint folder URL via REST

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I have a document library with multiple level folder structure, I want to fetch the server relative URL of individual folder by their name.

For example:
Folder structure in lib like this:
Document Library > Folder => subfolder1 => subfolder2

If I pass Name='Folder', it should return /Document Library/Folder

If I pass Name='subfolder2', it should return /Document Library/Folder/subfolder1/subfolder2

I tried below restAPI:

```
_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Documents')/RootFolder?$expand=Folders/Folders&$Filter=Name eq 'subfolder2'
```

But it returns extra folder details as well.

Any extra parameter I can add to my rest URL to filter out extra folder details?

Answer (score 0):

Modified the REST URL a bit:

```
_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Documents')/Items?$expand=Folder&$select=Title,FileLeafRef,Folder/ServerRelativeUrl&$filter=(FSObjType eq 1 and Title eq 'subfolder2')
```

Comment: One catch here is: You (or any other user) have to update the Title column of folder every time you create new folder.